# Validate Pattern on Array Parameter

Tags: powershell

I have a script that accepts one or more subdomains, I want to validate them but `[ValidatePattern()]` seems to only check the first item in the array.

The code:

```
param(
    [ValidatePattern('\w*\.domain\.com')][string]$subdomain
)
```

This input gets accepted:

```
.\script.ps1 -subdomain "test.domain.com", "randomstring"
```

Is there a way to validate every entry in the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
param(
    [ValidatePattern('\w*\.domain\.com')][string[]]$subdomain
)
```

in your script subdomain parameter doesn't accept multiple values. 
`[string[]]$subdomain`